# Как заполнить поле инспектора из скрипта редактора снаружи

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется вот такой код

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject map;


void OnValidate()
{
map = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("map");
}
```

Он добавляет в поле инспектора объект, который находит на сцене. Но делает это изнутри самого скрипта.

А как заполнить поле инспектора из скрипта редактора снаружи?

Хотелось бы что то вроде этого

Псведокод:

```
Asset assetForField = AssetDatabase.GetAssetByPath("assetForSerializeField")

Fields[] fields = AssetDatabase.GetSerializeFieldsOfGameObject("map");

foreach(field in fields)
{

if(field.name.Equals("_map")
{
field.FillSerializeField(assetForField);
}

}
```

Comment: Если переменная `private`, то никакой другой класс не имеет к нему доступа. Поле должно быть `public`.

Comment: @Yaroslav `SerializeField` же, через `SerializedObject` туда можно получить доступ.

Comment: @Yaroslav да и через рефлексию можно в общем то, но как назначить и сохранить, как в OnValidate?

Comment: Звиняюсь, не пользуюсь `SerializeField` и вопрос не правильно понял.

Comment: `OnValidate` происходит когда изменяешь поля в инспекторе, а вам насколько я понял нужно что-то типа `Start`, но в едиторе. Наверное проще будет написать `Custom Editors` c проверкой `if (map == null) map = GameObject.Find...`.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите этот код из `OnValidate()` и тогда в инспекторе нужно будет кинуть нужный object

Comment: Вопрос был не в этом. Мне нужно из другого скрипта назначить объект в сериализуемое поле любого объекта на сцене. 

Я даже в псевдокоде это написал, но напишу еще и так

Что мне нужно написать в скрипте А, чтобы он нашёл на сцене объект со скриптом Б, нашёл у этого скрипта  сериализуемое поле под именем В и запихнул туда объект Г?